# Kotlin - System.getProperty cannot resolve command line argument

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have some code to load `application.properties` dynamically:

```
fun loadDefaultProperties(): Properties {
    val configPath = System.getProperty("spring.config.location")
    val resource = FileSystemResource(configPath)
    return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource)
}
```

But when I run the command...

```
java -jar my.jar -Dspring.config.location=my/location/application.properties
```

...`System.getProperty("spring.config.location")` returns `null`, and therefore, I get an `IllegalArgumentException` because the path is `null`.

Why am I unable to read the argument from the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing them in the wrong sequence. Pass them like:

```
java "-Dspring.config.location=my/location/application.properties" -jar my.jar
```

Otherwise they are program arguments. I've just tested it, and on MacOS, both the above as well as

```
java -Dspring.config.location=my/location/application.properties -jar my.jar
```

(without quotes) work.

Comment: In that order I get `Error: Could not find or load main class .config.location=my/location/application.properties`

Comment: Try putting them in quotes, depending on your OS.

Comment: I've just tried it locally, and it works fine. Not sure why this is downvoted.

Comment: I tried in quotes as well. Still doesn't work :( I'm using Powershell on Windows

Comment: The second option didn't work for me. The first one did.

Comment: using Powershell and only the system properties in quotes did work for me, e.g. `java "-Dspring.config.location=test" -jar some.jar` worked ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need quotes?

```
java -jar my.jar -Dspring.config.location="my/location/application.properties"
```

Comment: you do not necessarily need quotes... `-DpropertyKey=value` should suffice, except there is a space or otherwise special symbol in the value...